# NetCFSvcUtil "Error: An error occurred in the tool."

Tags: wcf, compact-framework

I am trying to generate a WCF proxy client code for a Windows mobile application that uses basicHttpBinding and I'm continuously receiving the follow error:

**Error: An error occurred in the tool.**

**Error: Error in the application**

I was able to generate the proxy before but I don't know why suddenly this happens.
I have read the [Sameh Samir's](http://blogs.windowsclient.net/sameh/archive/2008/06/21/ambiguous-error-message-from-netcfsvcutil-exe.aspx) post but the service I use doesn't use any Message Contracts created by me (I've used LINQ to SQL ORD) and the WCFTestClient can connect to the service and shows the contracts.

**UPDATE**

It seems the problem was with the Windows 7 RC1. I was trying it on Win7 and after running the NetCFSvcUtil on XP everything works just fine.

Anyone knows how can I report this problem to the Microsoft?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

THere is now a new tool available that replaces the older version of NetCFSvcUtil.  It came out on Monday, August 10, 2009.  It can be downloaded at the following link:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/2/0/6205ED05-E435-44FC-AA82-B763CA5F8B1A/NetCFSvcUtil.exe

Best of luck!

Comment: I was about to give up on this, thinking the tool I **just downloaded today** would have the updated version of **NetCFSvcUtil.exe** - but it did not.

Answer (score 2):

I found this: http://blogs.msdn.com/habibh/archive/2009/06/26/netcfsvcutil-exe-and-windows-7.aspx

Basically, it states:
Currently, there are no fixes available for this issue. The only workaround is to run NetCFSvcUtil.exe on Windows Vista (SP1 or earlier) or Windows Server 2008 (SP1 or earlier) and then copy the generated client code to other machines.

Comment: An update exists in the article that you refer. There is a patch for the tool which you can download from the link provided by accepted Eric's answer.