# NetCFSvcUtil.exe gives Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: .net, wcf, compact-framework, wcf-client

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NetCFSvcUtil “Error: An error occurred in the tool.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992712/netcfsvcutil-error-an-error-occurred-in-the-tool)

When I try to generate classes for a wcf service using that tool, 
it gives me the above error.

I have somewhere found the fix for NetCFSvcUtil.exe but it doesn't resolve my problem.
My current version is: 3.5.9198.0 Is there somewhere a newer version?

has anyone experienced such problem?

Thanks

---

The output from console:

Microsoft (R) .NET Compact Framework Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 3.5.0.0]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Attempting to download metadata from 'http://10.1.0.168/FileTransfer' using WS-M
etadata Exchange or DISCO.
Warning: .NET Compact Framework does not support 'MessageHeaderAttribute' found
on 'RemoteFileInfo.Crc'.  Client proxy will support a reduced service contract.

Warning: .NET Compact Framework does not support 'MessageHeaderAttribute' found
on 'RemoteFileInfo.FileName'.  Client proxy will support a reduced service contr
act.

Warning: .NET Compact Framework does not support 'MessageHeaderAttribute' found
on 'RemoteFileInfo.Length'.  Client proxy will support a reduced service contrac
t.

Error: An error occurred in the tool.

### Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Contract:

```
namespace FileTransfer
{
  [ServiceContract(ConfigurationName = "IFileTransfer")]  
  public interface IFileTransfer
  {
    [OperationContract]
    RemoteFileInfo DownloadFile(DownloadRequest request);
  }

  [MessageContract]
  public class DownloadRequest
  {
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Guid ID;

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string App
  }

  [MessageContract]
  public class RemoteFileInfo : IDisposable
  {
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string FileName;

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public long Length;

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public int Crc;

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;

    public void Dispose()
    {
      if (FileByteStream != null)
      {
        FileByteStream.Close();
        FileByteStream = null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1267301/419956) will help? Seems the tool has been replaced.

Comment: That patch, is the hotfix I have downloaded. It doesn't solve my problem either

Answer (score 0):

I don't have or use `NetCFSvcUtil.exe`, but my guess is you have it referenced or included somehow in your project.

Notice how my program in the screenshot below shows that the Icon `palm.ico` is **NOT** copied to the device in the Properties window:

[image: screenshot]

You **DO** want this included in your output directory.

This is why you are getting a Null Reference Exception: The object isn't on your device.