# Generating WCF proxy for compact framework 2.0

Tags: wcf, compact-framework

I have a **WCF service written in VS 2010, .Net framework 4.0**. I am using **basicHttpBinding** in the service. I am trying to consume the service from a **.net compact framework 2.0** client. I have tried the netcfsvcutil but it always throws the "error in application" error.

(1) Can I use netcfsvcutil for generating proxy for compact framework 2.0 or it only supports cF 3.5? All the posts talk about this tool in context of CF 3.5.

(2) Can I use svcutil to generate the proxy?

(3) Is there any other way I can consume WCF service in a CF 2.0 client?

I have been looking for the answers since a week but couldnt find anything. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100%, but I'm fairly certain you are going to need to install the CF35 framework to your CF 2.0 devices.

You can download the redistributable, then just make that cab installer Step 1 before installing your application:

[.NET Compact Framework 3.5 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=65)

It sounds like you have already downloaded and installed the [NETCFv35PowerToys.msi](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13442), but did you know the **NetCFSvcUtil.exe** in it was outdated? There's an update for it here:

[Download New NetCFSvcUtil.exe from Microsoft](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/2/0/6205ED05-E435-44FC-AA82-B763CA5F8B1A/NetCFSvcUtil.exe)

Here is a post with more info:

[NetCFSvcUtil "Error: An error occurred in the tool."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/992712/153923)